# Dual citizenship - can have visa in one passport and use APM (automatic passport machines) with the other

Tags: visas, usa, us-visa-waiver-program, dual-nationality

I have Brazilian and Italian citizenship and passports.
Renewing the Brazilian passport I plan to apply for a USA visa on it.

Is it true that from that moment on I MUST enter the USA using exclusively the Brazilian passport? I mean: no longer benefiting from the visa waiver program (VWP) until the visa is expired?

The reason for my question is quite simple: While I don't need to use the VWP, if I have a valid visa I would like to keep using the automated passport machines available in the airport I normally use when go to the States. Those machines are for US citizens/residents and ESTA (VWP) users.

The question may sound odd, but I was told that IF you have a valid visa you SHOULD use that passport to enter the US. (therefore entering the regular immigration line).  Of course when I travel I have both passports with me.

Comment: Why would you apply for a visa if you're VWP-eligible? And why not apply for one for your Italian passport then?

Comment: VWP is less flexible  than a regular VISA. For instance, the maximum stay is limited to 90 days. There are other limitations.

Comment: Friends told me that. In fact that was BEFORE the machines were installed. May be the current practice is different.

Comment: Note that just about any recent press on APC machines now includes the fact that B1/B2 visa holders can use the machines. E.g. see [this, from the Bahamas](http://www.bahamas.gov.bs/wps/portal/public/gov/government/news/b1%20b2%20visa%20holders%20with%20electronic%20passports%20cleared%20to%20use%20automated%20passport%20control%20kiosks%20at%20lpia), or [this, from Hawaii](http://hidot.hawaii.gov/blog/2016/05/10/international-travelers-see-45-percent-reduction-in-processing-times-because-of-new-automated-passport-control-kiosks/).

Comment: The CBP site and many airport's signs don't say this yet but there's a good chance you can, or will soon be able to, use the passport with the visa at APC machines.

Comment: Travelers could use the APC in Atlanta with a B1/B2 visa this past June.

Comment: "VWP is less flexible than a regular visa": but if you have a US visa in your Brazilian passport and you use the Italian passport to enter without a visa, you will have entered on the VWP and you won't benefit from any of the flexibility.

Answer (score 3):

From personal experience (although not with the US), I had a current Schengen visa in one of my passports when I got my US citizenship. On my next trip to Europe I used my US passport, despite having another passport with a still valid visa which was valid for the purpose of the visit. Nobody asked any questions.

Now regarding the USA, I have found no specific information about it in FAMs or on DoS website about that. Thus my answer would be more of a <s>speculation</s> conclusion, and it would be "**no, you would not be required** to use a specific passport to enter the USA" simply because you have a visa in that passport. Consider the typical case where the passport with the visa is no longer in your possession because it has been replaced/lost/damaged.

Interestingly enough, the US visa application form doesn't even ask about all your nationalities.

Answer (score 3):

If you have two nationalities, you may enter the US using either one you wish.

[If you enter](https://help.cbp.gov/app/answers/detail/a_id/1094/kw/dual%20passport) using a VWP-eligible nationality, you must have an ESTA, and if you enter using a nationality that requires a visa, you must have a visa.

> I have dual citizenship from both a VWP country and a non-VWP country?
>
> If you are flying under the terms of the VWP, with your VWP passport, you must apply for ESTA. If you are using your non-VWP country's passport, you will require a visa and therefore ESTA does not apply to you.

Comment: Small nitpick: if you enter with a VWP eligible passport, you can still choose to get a B visa in that passport and not use the VWP, thereforenot requiringESTA  . But if the B visa is in *another* passport, as it is in this case, the traveler would have to use the VWP.